# Problems trying to render some data on chartjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to do a chart that will render some data fetched from a database.

I have the following query which returns the testatm key, and I'm sending this data to front end using a promise. I used it to render a table on my view.

```
const testeAtM = atendimentos.aggregate([
            {
                '$group':
                    {
                        '_id':
                            {'id_atendente': "$id_atendente", 'month': {'$month': '$date'}},
                        'sum': {'$sum': 1}
                    }
            },
            {'$sort': {'_id': 1}},
            {
                '$group': {
                    '_id': null,
                    'testatm': {'$push': '$$ROOT'}
                }
            },
        ]).exec()
```

I want to make a chart where the x axis is the id_atendente and the y axis will have the number of occurrences per id_atendente (which is the sum on my query)

**EDIT 1**

My promise is this one:

```
Promise.all([counts, monthly, testeAt, atendData, testeEa, testeAtM]).then(([counts, monthly, testeAt, atendData, testeEa, testeAtM]) => {
            const statusData = counts[0];
            const monthlyData = monthly[0];
            const atData = testeAt[0];
            const dataAtend = atendData[0];
            const dataEa = testeEa[0];
            const atendAtM = testeAtM[0];

            //O operador spread ... reestrutura tudo em apenas um objeto
            const data = {
                ...statusData, ...monthlyData, ...atData, ...dataAtend, ...dataEa, ...atendAtM,
                user: req.user
            };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

            res.render('home', data);
        }).catch(err => next(err));
```

I tried to make something like that:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [<%= testatm._id.id_atendente %>],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Gráfico de atendimento',
                    data: [<%= testatm._id.sum %>], // parâmetros do banco
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(71, 87, 112)',
                        'rgb(229, 226, 27)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgb(71, 87, 112)',
                        'rgb(229, 226, 27)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

But it didn't work. I rendered the table using the data like this:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < testatm.length; i++) { %>
<%= testatm[i]._id.id_atendente %>
                <%= testatm[i].sum %>
                <%= testatm[i]._id.month %>
        <% } %>
```

And it works.

I don't know why using something like that doesn't works on chart. I'm using EJS template by the way.

Hope I can get some help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing your data using the wrong expression. To access JSON data in your script in EJS template do this

```
var myData = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(dataFromServer) %>'); //use <%- not <%=
console.log(myData)    //try logging to check if you are actually getting any data
```

now you can access your data for charts.

**EDIT**

In case you already have strigified data, parse it into JSON before using it

```
var myData = JSON.parse('<%- dataFromServer %>');
```

Comment: Not sure, I have a JSON.stringify after my promise, I'll edit my question and add the promise

Comment: in that case, you still need to parse your data into JSON. I have edited my answer

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out, but now I'm just wondering how I'm able to use the data to make a table on my view and for the chart it doens't works lol

Comment: By the way, I have a working chart here using the data fetched and I'm able to use the key returned from mongo to render the data.